# ExtJS4 Perfomance tuning

Tags: grid, extjs4

We are developing application in ExtJS4.

using extjs4, WCF Service, with editor grid, and perfomance is very very very slow. application is running under IE 8. Can someone provide tips on tuning the perfomance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extjs in general has performance issues with IE .. i guess you are using the 4.0.7 the latest release. You can wait for 4.1.0 which should be a lot faster especially on IE, see their performance preview [here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-developer-preview/)

Answer (score 2):

1. Reduce number of record by paging. (max 25)
2. Reduce number of columns displayed. (max10)
3. Reduce server time to load by optimizing query, should also page by 25.
4. Use a modern browser (FF,Chrome,etc)

Comment: paging is possible, however server side code is optimized good enough. IE comes with default build used in business division, so no choice of going to FF, Chrome.

Comment: "IE comes with default build used in business division, so no choice of going to FF, Chrome."  ---- RUN!! Run like the wind!

Comment: You asked a very general question, so is my answer. If you need a more specific suggestion you going to have to provide a bit more about what you are doing and where exactly is slowness. What you really need is a code review. If you have something very specific - post your code sample and we can take a look .

Comment: sure. i can post the code, however the main perfomance hit we are seeing is while rendering. so not sure it requires Ext upgrade, as seen lot of posts with perfomance issue with ExtJs 4.0.6 and IE. Even there is post on sencha site, that after upgrade to ExtJs 4.1 you can get lot better perfomance. I was just trying to find out if without upgrade we can figure out some tweaks that can give better perfomance, as dont want to upgrade now after lot of testing.

Comment: Just an FYI, I am using 4.0.2 and don't have much of a performance issue. Lot's depend on your design and requirements.